# Webview android couldn't load HTML5

Tags: android, android-webview, xwalkview

My Android app is upgrade to API 29, so we need to change from Xwalkcorelibrary to WebView, when run app can show HTML5 but the content of this page is not show.

When use WebView:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.bookshelf_view);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
    try {
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUserAgentString(webSettings.getUserAgentString() + " " + AndroidCore.getInstance().getApiVersion());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HTML5/index.html");
```

When use Xwalkcorelibrary :

```
 try {
        Method getBridge = XWalkView.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBridge");
        getBridge.setAccessible(true);
        XWalkViewBridge xWalkViewBridge = null;
        xWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge) getBridge.invoke(mXwalkView);
        XWalkSettings webSettings = xWalkViewBridge.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUserAgentString(
                webSettings.getUserAgentString() + " " + AndroidCore.getInstance().getApiVersion());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mXwalkView.setResourceClient(new MyResourceClient(mXwalkView));
    mXwalkView.setUIClient(new MyUIClient(mXwalkView));
    this.configureWebView();
    mXwalkView.loadAppFromManifest("file:///android_asset/manifest.json", null)
```

So what I did wrong ? Please help me figure out solution ?

Comment: Have you added ` android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` this one in your manifest file?

Comment: I also try your suggestion but still can't help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this It is working for me in my project :

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);


    webView.loadUrl("URL");
```

Intercepting WebView HTTP Requests

```
public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

private Activity activity = null;

public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.indexOf("jenkov.com") > -1 ) return false;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}

@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/logo.png")){
        String mimeType = "image/png";
        String encoding = "";
        InputStream input = ...;


        WebResourceResponse response =
                new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);

        return response;
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Caching Values in HTML 5 Local Storage

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Oh ! Thank you so much ! I can load full page HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest file. Sometimes webview can't load for video and iframes `hardwareAccelerated`.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Also you may try with changing the file url -

Try changing this - 
`mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HTML5/index.html");`

To
`mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

Comment: That attribute android:hardwareAccelerated="true" is added in my AndroidManifest before, The link you request me "file:///android_asset/index.html" isn't exactly. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I have suggested you to - try with changing the index.html file location android_asset/HTML5 directory to android_asset folder.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I can load full page